# How to pin out "Sound" to Windows taskbar?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, control-panel

**Context**

I am using very ofter the Sound settings. It seems to be a normal application with taskbar icon, still I can not pin it, because this context menu item is missing.

I would like to start it with a single click from the taskbar.

**Question**

How can I pin out this application to the taskbar?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- create a new shortcut elsewhere using mouse rightclick -> *New* -> *Shortcut*
- target `%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL "mmsys.cpl"`, <kbd>Next</kbd>
- name `Sound`,  <kbd>Finish</kbd>
- change the `Sound` shortcut icon using mouse rightclick -> *Properties*  (choose e.g. from `mmsys.cpl`)
- move the `Sound` shortcut to taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually fairly easy to do.  Here is an excellent [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtRaVHDwvKA) that provides step by step instructions.

Brief summary:  Open Control Panel, create a shortcut of the sound applet, then create a shortcut, then create an Explorer based shortcut to the shortcut you just made.  You can then move that to the taskbar.

As an alternative, I use a program called [Audio Switcher](https://audioswit.ch/er#download), which might give you the functionality you desire, in the task tray.